# Why should I set max_length when using Choices in a Django model?

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms, django-2.0

In the official [Django 2 tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/) I found this:

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

Now my question is does using choices mean that only either of the four defined values is valid for this field? If so what is the use of specifying the `max_length`? If not, why not use a validator that validates if the value is actually exacly one of the specified ones or at least a validator that only accepts an specific length not just an upper bound.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "only either of the four defined values is valid". Any of those values is valid. You need max_length because the database needs to know how many characters to allocate to the field.

Comment: I mean like would this model trow an exception if a value like 'A' or 'RU' is set to it that is not defined in the choices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`max_length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length) is enforced at the database level, but the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) are enforced at python code level (when calling `full_clean()` or `clean_<fieldname>()`).

They are independent of each other.

If you set a value to your field other than the specified choices and you **don't** call `instance.full_clean()` or `instance.clean_<fieldname>()`, it could still get saved to the database without raising errors.

But if you use djangos forms, the `choices` validation is done for you (the form calls `full_clean()`) and you don't need to worry about it.

---

This means, for example, if you set `max_length` smaller than your largest option in `choices`, your database will silently truncate the values for that field or raise a `DatabaseError`; either way you will not get it to work.

This separation is useful, for example, if you want to add more choices later; if the new options are not larger than `max_length`, there will be no need to to change the database structure (that means, the new migration will **NOT** issue `alter table` SQL statements).

Comment: Oh thanks. so now do you think it's better that I use a regex validator to make sure that it will be exactly one of the options?

Comment: No, the validators are run at the same level (python code) than the `choices` validation. As long as you use forms or call `instance.full_clean()`, the `choices` validation will be done and there is no need for other validators.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently, except that I wasn't just using a two letter code so it was a bit tedious to make sure I had a valid max_length. I ended up doing something like this:

```
year_in_school = models.CharField(
    max_length=max(len(v[0]) for v in YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES),
    choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
    default=FRESHMAN,
)
```

If I ever add an option that exceeds the existing max length, makemigrations will detect that and add that change to the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I found it convenient to extend TextChoices with a property that can be used to set max_length:

```
TextChoicesMeta = type(models.TextChoices)


class ExtendedTextChoicesMeta(TextChoicesMeta):
    @property
    def max_length(cls) -> int:
        return max(len(value) for value in cls.values)


class ExtendedTextChoices(models.TextChoices, metaclass=ExtendedTextChoicesMeta):
    pass


class PropertyType(ExtendedTextChoices):
    RESIDENTIAL = "RESIDENTIAL", _("residential")
    COMMERCIAL = "COMMERCIAL", _("commercial")
    INDUSTRIAL = "INDUSTRIAL", _("industrial")
    RAW_LAND = "RAW_LAND", _("raw land")
    SPECIAL_USE = "SPECIAL_USE", _("special use")


class Property(models.Model):
    property_type = models.CharField(
        choices=PropertyType.choices,
        max_length=PropertyType.max_length,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For django 3 and highter and `models.TextChoices`

```py
class DocumentTypeChoices(models.TextChoices):
    PHOTO = 'PHOTO', _('Photo')
    DOC = 'DOC', _('Document')

...

document_type = models.CharField(
    choices=DocumentTypeChoices.choices,
    max_length=max(len(choice) for choice, _ in DocumentTypeChoices.choices),
)
```